# instance Of Operator in java

Tags: java, instanceof

```
class A {}

class B {}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a instanceof B);
    }

}
```

This code is giving compile time error. 
How can I use `instanceof` to give false instead of compile time error when object is not an instance of class specified.

Comment: Did you compile `class A` and `class B` all in the same file?

Comment: Try with `Object a = new A();`

Answer (score 4):

Java knows an `A` cannot be a `B` so it won't compile. If you change the line to

```
Object a = new A();
```

it will compile (and return false) as it can no longer tell if an `Object` can be cast into type `B`.

Comment: I mean to say that insanceof eturn true if object is instance of a class and false if not ..... but when i am tryimg the second case then it is not giving false instead giving compile time error....... but as the definition says that it has two values true and false and it gives false if object is not an instance of class so how to get false.

Comment: It will never compile when you are using it with unrelated types. `instanceof` is meant for situations where the object in question could legitimately be the type you are testing, e.g. `myBird instanceof Eagle`

Comment: @Ankit because compiler knows that according to specification variable of type A (which has nothing to do with B) can't hold instance of B so such test will never return true, so there is no point even writing it. Writing such code was most likely based on incorrect assumption so it is better to stop programmer now instead of letting him make mistake.

Comment: In your case the compiler has enough information to tell you (with a compile error) that an `A` can _never_ be a `B`. When the compiler does not have this information like in a polymorphism (or raw `Object` reference) situation, `instanceof` can be used

Answer (score 2):

If `class A` and `B` are not related through inheritance, then compiler will throw an error when you try to perform `a instanceof B`

In your case, `A` is NOT a subclass of `B`, so you can't do an `instanceof` check like `a instanceof B`

But, if you change your classes like below:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   B b=new B();
   System.out.println(b instanceof A);
}
```

Now `b instanceof A` will return `true` because **`B` IS-A (type of) `A`**

You can read the Java doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) on the same subject:

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You
>   can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
>   of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
>   interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
System.out.println(a.getClass().equals(B.class));
```

Instead of :

```
System.out.println(a instanceof B);
```

Comment: This isn't the same. For example, `"".getClass().equals(Object.class)` is false, but `"" instanceof Object` is true. `instanceof` matches subclasses, `equals` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [JLS Sec 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> If a cast (§15.16) of the `RelationalExpression` to the `ReferenceType` would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression could never be true.

(Where they are describing `RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType`)

You can't write `B b = (B) a;` either, because `A` and `B` are both classes (*), and are unrelated, in the sense that `A` does not directly or indirectly extend `B`, nor vice versa.

As such, a reference to an `A` can never contain an instance of a `B`, so it is nonsensical to test this. As such, the compiler stops you from testing this, as it likely indicates a logical error.

---

(*) You could write `a instanceof B` if `B` were an interface, because `a` might refer to a subclass of `A` which additionally implements `B`, e.g.

```
class ChildOfA extends A implements B {}
A a = new ChildOfA();
System.out.println(a instanceof B); // fine.
```